# How do I reset this switch so I can use it?

Tags: router, switch

I bought a used **24 port Enterasys VH-2402S fast Ethernet switch** at a government surplus warehouse for use at a small private school.

After researching, I found that it is a level 2 and level 3 switch and is password protected.  The switch will not work for us the way it is configured, and I can't change its configuration without a password, and I have no way to get it from the sys-admins who sent it off to surplus.

Is there any way to flush the NV-RAM and reset the switch without having the password?  I'm not beyond taking it apart and shorting contacts and such if it would help.

Comment: I don't have direct personal experience with Enterasys gear, but that's what our network team at my $work have deployed (to the tune of hundreds of switches along with a handful of their "core" routers). I'll see if I can ask them about Enterasys password recovery while at work tomorrow.

Comment: What does the manual say?

Comment: http://www.andovercg.com/datasheets/entrasys-vh-2402-l3.pdf

Comment: Try username "tiger" and password "tiger123"

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff, I read through that.  It's for the L3, not the S and I did see that I could do a factory reset, but I was under the impression that I had to be logged in as admin to do so.

Comment: I see what you mean, I bet a phone call to them will get you an answer, even without a support contract they should have a KB article on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to delete configuration files pre-boot like on a cisco device, at least not any documented way, however there seems to be an admin password generated with every MAC, but you have to contact entarasys to have them generate it for you:

http://www.mail-archive.com/enterasys@listserv.unc.edu/msg00629.html